# Oracle SQL Query Get Value at Max Date

Tags: sql, oracle

Data:

```
| ORIGL_ORDER | ORDER | ITEM | DATE        | WHSE | QTY |
| ----------- | ----- | ---- | ----------  | ---- | --- |
| 001         | 107   | 9    | 12/29/2020  | 7    | 6   |
| 001         | 110   | 9    | 12/30/2020  | 1    | 4   |
| 001         | 113   | 9    | 12/30/2020  | 3    | 2   |
| 007         | 211   | 3    | 12/20/2020  | 6    | 1   |
| 007         | 219   | 3    | 12/19/2020  | 5    | 3   | 
| 018         | 390   | 8    | 12/25/2020  | 2    | 1   |
```

Original Desired Result:

```
| ORIGL_ORDER | ORDER | ITEM | MAX_DATE    | WHSE |
| ----------- | ----- | ---- | ----------  | ---- |
| 001         | 113   | 9    | 12/30/2020  | 3    |
| 007         | 211   | 3    | 12/20/2020  | 6    |
| 018         | 390   | 8    | 12/25/2020  | 2    |
```

Original Question: For each ORIGL_ORDER and ITEM, I would like to get the max(DATE) and the WHSE corresponding to the max(Date). If there are more than one orders with the same max(DATE) then the select the largest ORDER number.

New Desired Result:

```
| ORIGL_ORDER | ORDER | ITEM | MAX_DATE    | WHSE | TOTAL_QTY |
| ----------- | ----- | ---- | ----------  | ---- | --------- |
| 001         | 113   | 9    | 12/30/2020  | 3    | 12        |
| 007         | 211   | 3    | 12/20/2020  | 6    | 4         |
| 018         | 390   | 8    | 12/25/2020  | 2    | 1         |
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answers the original version of the question.

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ORIGL_ORDER, item order by date desc, order_number desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I think this will work to get my new desired result: ```select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by ORIGL_ORDER, item order by date desc, order_number desc) as seqnum, sum(QTY) over (partition by ORIGL_ORDER, ITEM) as TOTAL_QTY
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff can you write this query with oracle ddl i am getting Unable to resolve symbol 't'